# dynamicpage.js modifying so IE won't recognize FADE effect

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, plugins

if Someone has knowledge of this jquery plugin PLEASE can you help me to configure it so IE WON'T recognize the Fade effect it produces but STILL can use the AJAX.  IS there a way to add some browser detection to the plugin file or should I have 2 separate methods of navigation and use conditional comments ?

http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, *dynamicpage.js* doesn't even contain a jquery plugin. So you might as well go ahead and modify the content of the file directly. It's pretty short.

You could then use jQuery's `$.support` or even `$.browser` ([not necessarily recommendable](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)) method to split your code depending on the browser. Or even better extract your solution into a function or plugin and call it from within conditional comments as you need it.

Since I'm assuming that the reason you want to do this, are certain issues with IE when it comes to animating the `opacity` property, you might want to have a look at these

- [jquery IE Fadein and Fadeout Opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284163/jquery-ie-fadein-and-fadeout-opacity)
- [jQuery FadeIn loses transparency on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334583/jquery-fadein-loses-transparency-on-ie)
- [jQuery fadeIn IE Png Issue when loading from external](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808015/jquery-fadein-ie-png-issue-when-loading-from-external)

as well and maybe just "fix" the code you already have.

**UPDATE**
By request: You can detect IE using `browser` like this:

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
    // do something only for IE
} else {
    // do something for all other browsers
}
```

Again — this is not necessarily recommendable, since browser detection has been always problematic. Depending on what exactly it is that you're trying to fix, you might want consider implementing a different approach.